# Java - Unable to stop runnable from main class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am banging my heads against the desk here friends. This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a Main class, that will create a new thread. Right now, when the thread is done working, it will perform some minor clean, and the thread is stopped. However, I have a "Stop" button on the UI, that when pressed, should "do some cleanup, then kill the thread. The problem is, I can't seem to update anything that is inside of that new thread that I created.

Here are some snippets:

Main Class

```
runner = new Thread(new Controller1(options));
runner.start();
```

In the Above code, I'm calling my Controller1 class, and setting some "options" in the constructor. This is working good so far...

Now, in the Controller1 class, this is what I have...

```
public volatile static boolean stopped;

public void run() {
    while(!stopped ){
        System.out.println("In run");
        startProxy(proxyPort);
        startWebDriver();
        driver.get(http);
        UIMainJSwing1.updateStartButton();
        stopped=true;
    }

    //Run killAll to stop webdriver and the proxy
    killAll();
    System.out.println("Thread complete");
}
```

The problem is, from the Main class, I can't call or set "stopped" to true. I can call runner.interrupt(), but the problem is, since the thread just dies, my killAll() function is never ran, and I'm left with the WebDriver and Proxy still running.

Comment: Good point on the While loop, I think I put that in there, because I was trying to find a way to stop this thread from my Main. Now that I have it removed, yes, it runs once, but is there anyway to have an override that will take it out of the run() method and to the killAll()?

Comment: Any blocking calls in that loop?

Comment: @Whnunlife If you find any answer helpful you should upvote and or accept it, ie. Gray's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call `thread.interupt()` in your main thread and use a a [`try` / `finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) around the loop in your `Runnable` to make sure your `killAll()` method is called.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (!stopped) {
            ...
        }
    } finally {
        //Run killAll to stop webdriver and the proxy
        killAll();
        System.out.println("Thread complete");
    }
}
```

The finally block will *always* be called.  Even if the thread is interrupted or throws an exception.

Couple other comments:

And you mention the `volatile boolean stopped` flag but you are setting that to be true immediately at the end of the loop so I do see why you have a loop at all.

Assuming that the thread doesn't run through and immediately call `killAll()` then it is hanging somewhere in one of the methods.  When you call `interrupt()` from the main thread, whatever is being waiting on will throw an `InterruptedException`. But since I don't see any catching going on, maybe the methods are re-throwing it as a `RuntimeException`?  They should at least be doing something like the following but this still blocks the exception:

```
 try {
     something.wait();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // restore the interrupted condition
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 }
```

Regardless the try/finally is the right way to go to ensure the `killAll` is called.

Comment: `catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // restore the interrupted condition
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 }` this could still be eating the exception, if it's in some kind of `while (true)` loop

Comment: True @artbristol. I've tweaked my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Question, this try / catch, that should go in the run() method of my runnable correct?

Comment: Right.  Around your stopped loop.  Basically whatever you start should be in the `try` and the `finally` should have the `killAll`.

Comment: But getting back to my Main class, how would I go about and update the new thread that is created and set "stopped = false" so the thread will stop?

Comment: @Whnunlife, sorry you should then use `interrupt()` in main and the try/finally in your thread loop.

Comment: in my run(), since that is called from my main class, what would I be trying to "try" in my try catch? If I paste in my try/catch in the run, like 'try {
   startProxy(proxyPort);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // restore the interrupted condition
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }' I get the hint in eclipse to remove the "catch" statement

Comment: @Whnunlife No need to catch anything.  Just have a `try { ... } finally { ... }`.   See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Great @Whnunlife.  Don't forget to check/accept the answer and +1 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably catch InterruptedException, so that your killAll() method gets run.
Just use a try/finally

Second, why can't you set stopped=true from your main method?

Comment: I've tried that, so what I did to test it out, was inside the run(), remove the stopped = true at the end of the while statement. So if I run it, it's just a loop. Then I tried to set that value from Main when clicking on the button, but the loop never exits.

Comment: if you look into code wich uses "interrupted", you will see that in run() method it checks if interrupted==true and throws InterruptedException. Just similar to your stopped==true.
The point is: you by no means can interrupt running thread by force from another thread. You should check in your code in run() at any point if execution still should run. If not - exit or throw InterruptedException. All by yourself :)
Instead of stopped you can use isInterrupted() method wich is present in Thread class, and call interrupt() from main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info there, so I should basically have a while(!isInterrupted()) Then, if I call thread.interrupt, it will get check as true and get get caught right?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right you misuse the while(!stopped) idiom. In your code you check if it not stopped once, and then do all the things to the end, set stopped=true and exit. You just don't give a chance to stop execution after it started. When it started the stopped field will be never adressed again until it is over.

Answer (score 0):

First, lose the `while(!stopped)` and `stopped=true` parts.
Also you need to evaluate `stopped` at every separate stage in the the thread (and remember to run killAll() and re-enable the start button of course).

Comment: I changed my run() method around and wrapped each function in a if(!stopped), that way, if I set stopped = true from my main, the next function will not run and the killAll is called. Think I got it working, looks like amateur code, but oh well.